# Customizing properties of subclassed UITableViewCell when selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, customization

I am having trouble customizing the look and behavior of a subclassed tableview cell when it enters selected state.

My cell has three labels I added to its content view in the **`initWithStyle:`** method as such:

```
cell1Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(75.0f, 12.0f, 67.0f, 12.0f)];
cell1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell1Label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell1Label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   blah, blah, blah...

[self.contentView addSubview:cell1Label];
```

Then, I put a black overlay on top of the background in the **`setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated`** method within the subclass:

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 70.0f)];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:
0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.4];
self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;
```

The problem start here. Because I want to keep my `UILabel` readable when the cell is selected, I need to change their `textColor` and `shadowColor`. However, I cannot seem to find a good place to do this.

If I put the code in the **`setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated`** nothing happens; I can only seem to add changes to the **`selectedBackgroundView`**.

I also tried using the **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`** and **`didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`** TableView delegate methods as such:

```
CustomDataCell* selectedCell = (CustomDataCell*)[tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
selectedCell.cell1Label.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
selectedCell.cell1Label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

This method, however, has some issues when cells leave the visible area. Namely, if I select a cell then it leaves the visible area, its text properties do not change back to their normal state when I select another cell. The black background disappears as it should, but the new `textColor` and `shadowColor` I assigned to the selected state persists.

What is the *best*, *most reliable* way to handle selected (and possibly other) states of subclassed `UITableViewCells`?

I am using `ARC`; never use `IB`; on `Xcode 4.6` and `iOS 6.1` SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setHighlighted:animated` method of `UITableViewCell` to change your label `color`.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Change you label text color here
    //
    // Edit Here

    if (selected) {
        // New Colors Here
    }
    else {
        // Old Colors Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. For some reason, this method set all my text- and shadowColors for their normal state.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Looking through some code I also overrode setSelected:animated: which similar changed to the label color.

Comment: This did not work because selected is not the same as highlighted (the highlighted brach of the if statement never actually got called). But by applying the same logic within the setSelected:(BOOL)selected method, the code worked. If you could update your code to reflect the correct way, I'll mark you as best answer.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know why the selected text properties change back to normal when the cell leaves the visible area and then re-enters but not the background I set for selectedBackgroundView?

Comment: Not sure.  I'm not able to try at the moment.  You can get the current selected cell, [table indexPathForSelectedRow], and configure you cell as needed.

Answer (score 0):

When a cell is selected, it will set all of its labels (including ones you've added yourself) to their highlighted state. This means you can define the highlighted text color at initialisation and let the cell take care of it.

Probably at the moment the labels are being set to highlighted which is undoing any colour changes you are making yourself.

Also, a cell has a selectedBackgroundView property which you should be using instead of adding a new subview.

Comment: This works for text colors, but shadow colors do not have a highlighted state.

Comment: True, you'd have to set those in setSelected - I was explaining why your attempt to change the colours wasn't working.